# Type Error Warning keeps occurring in my code

Tags: python, numpy

In my python code, I keep getting the following error:

TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc svd_n

the code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def sdm_3eqs():
    def f_bold(x):
        return [15*x[0] + x[1]**2 - 4*x[2] - 15, x[0]**2 + 10*x[1] - x[2] - 10, x[1]**3 - 25*x[2] + 24]
    
    def f(x):
        f_n = []
        for i in range(len(x)):
            f_i = f_bold[i]**2
            f_n.append(f_i)
    
        return np.sum(f_n)
    
    def M(x):
        m = np.array([[15, 2*x[0], 0], [2*x[1], 10, 3*x[1]**2], [-4, -1, -25]])
        return m
    
    def grad_f(x):
        return 2*M(x)*f_bold(x)
    
    def d(x):
        return -grad_f(x)/norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)
    
    def s_prime(x, alpha, d):
        return grad_f(x + alpha*d)*d
    
    x = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
    iter = 0
    err = 100

    while err > 0.005:
        x_k = x
        d_k = d(x_k)

        m = 0
        sprime = 300
        alpha_l = 0
        alpha_u = 1.5
        alpha = (alpha_l+alpha_u)/2
        while abs(sprime) > 0.0005:
            alpha = (alpha_l+alpha_u)/2
            sprime = s_prime(x_k, alpha, d_k)[0][0]

            if abs(sprime) < 0.001:
                break
            elif sprime > 0:
                alpha_u = alpha
            else:
                alpha_l = alpha
            
            m += 1
        
        iter += 1
        x = x_k + alpha*d_k
        err = norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)/max(1, norm(f_bold(x), ord=2))
    
    print(f'f_bold: {f_bold(x)}')

sdm_3eqs()
```

I am unsure why but it says the type error come from line 57 in the code:

```
err = norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)/max(1, norm(f_bold(x), ord=2))
```

If anyone can help, that would be great!

EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method.py", line 61, in <module>
    sdm_3eqs()
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/Desktop/Scripts/Python/University of Greenwich/MATH1157/Scripts/Steepest Descent Method.py", line 57, in sdm_3eqs
    err = norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)/max(1, norm(f_bold(x), ord=2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in norm
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2579, in norm
    ret =  _multi_svd_norm(x, row_axis, col_axis, amax)
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2355, in _multi_svd_norm
    result = op(svd(y, compute_uv=False), axis=-1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in svd
  File "/Users/aidanpayne/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1673, in svd
    s = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc svd_n
```

Comment: Show the **full** traceback.  I don't see a `svd_n` function call in your code, but the traceback should tell us how that's being called.  You then need to check the type and dtype of arguments to this function, to see what is different from the documentation.

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: So it's one of the `norm` calls.  What's the `shape` and `dtype` of these arguments: `grad_f(x)`  `f_bold(x)`

Comment: Couldn't show dtype but the shapes are: Shape of grad_f = (3, 3); shape of f_bold = ()

Comment: I think there's a problem with what your grad_f function is returning; check your outputs from that function match the outputs you expect (in terms of shape/structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it.

In some of the functions, it was supposed to be the dot product of two matrices.

e.g.:

```
def grad_f(x):
    return 2*np.dot(M(x), f_bold(x))
```

Here's the updated code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.core.fromnumeric import shape
from numpy.linalg import norm
from numpy import transpose
from numpy import array
from numpy import sum
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def sdm_3eqs():
    def f_bold(x):
        x_1 = x[0]
        x_2 = x[1]
        x_3 = x[2]
        return array([15*x_1 + x_2**2 - 4*x_3 - 15, x_1**2 + 10*x_2 - x_3 - 10, x_2**3 - 25*x_3 + 24], dtype='float32')
    
    def f(x):
        f_n = []
        for i in range(len(x)):
            f_i = f_bold[i]**2
            f_n.append(f_i)
    
        return sum(f_n)
    
    def M(x):
        x_1 = x[0]
        x_2 = x[1]
        d1 = 2*x_1
        d2 = 2*x_2
        d3 = 3*x_2**2
        return array([[15, d1, 0], [d2, 10, d3], [-4, -1, -25]], dtype='float32')
    
    def grad_f(x):
        return 2*np.dot(M(x), f_bold(x))
    
    def d(x):
        return -1*grad_f(x)/norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)
    
    def s_prime(x, alpha, d):
        return np.dot(transpose(grad_f(x + alpha*d)), d)
    
    x = array([[0.5], [0.5], [0.5]], dtype='float32')
    iter = 0
    err = 100

    while err > 0.005:
        x_k = x
        d_k = d(x_k)

        m = 0
        sprime = 300
        alpha_l = 0
        alpha_u = 1.5
        alpha = (alpha_l+alpha_u)/2
        while abs(sprime) > 0.0005:
            alpha = (alpha_l+alpha_u)/2
            sprime = s_prime(x_k, alpha, d_k)
            
            if abs(sprime) < 0.001:
                break
            elif sprime > 0:
                alpha_u = alpha
            else:
                alpha_l = alpha
            
            m += 1
        
        iter += 1
        x = x_k + alpha*d_k
        err = norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)/max(1, norm(f_bold(x), ord=2))
    
    print(f'\nf_bold:\nEquation 1 = {f_bold(x)[0][0]}\nEquation 2 = {f_bold(x)[1][0]}\nEquation 3 = {f_bold(x)[2][0]}\n')

sdm_3eqs()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `M(x)` function is returning a 3-dimensional array, of structure

```
[
  [   a    [b c d]    e   ]
  [[f g h]    i    [k l m]]
  [   n       o       p   ]
]
```

and then you're attempting to matrix-multiply that with the result of `f_bold(x)` and calculate the norm.

I believe the error is related to trying to calculate the norm of this irregular matrix. In particular, check your function definition for `M(x)` to verify the shape/regularity of its returned array.

```py
line 17: m = np.array([[15, 2*x[0], 0], [2*x[1], 10, 3*x[1]**2], [-4, -1, -25]])
                              ^^^^         ^^^^        ^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a couple of prints to your code, and got this run:

```
In [63]: sdm_3eqs()
<ipython-input-62-2b082fcea817>:14: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  m = np.array([[15, 2*x[0], 0], [2*x[1], 10, 3*x[1]**2], [-4, -1, -25]])

f_bold
 [array([ 6.64610017e-05, -8.57391288e+00, -1.40877199e+01]), array([-3.81306816, -3.03705309, -6.81097338]), array([ 15.47764768,  12.41073581, -18.41883603])]

grad_f
 array([[0.0019938300511945783,
        array([-36.8081748 , -17.89173085, -17.14782575]), -0.0],
       [array([ -8.20903822, -10.93449844,  -7.0767119 ]),
        -60.74106175194817,
        array([-11.83793275, -21.00337307,  -8.79740011])],
       [-123.82118142652486, -24.821471626766595, 920.9418016830625]],
      dtype=object)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-63-8732d4079184>", line 1, in <module>
    sdm_3eqs()
  File "<ipython-input-62-2b082fcea817>", line 57, in sdm_3eqs
    err = np.linalg.norm(grad_f(x), ord=2)/max(1, np.linalg.norm(f_bold(x), ord=2))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in norm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2579, in norm
    ret =  _multi_svd_norm(x, row_axis, col_axis, amax)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2355, in _multi_svd_norm
    result = op(svd(y, compute_uv=False), axis=-1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in svd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 1672, in svd
    s = gufunc(a, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)
UFuncTypeError: Cannot cast ufunc 'svd_n' input from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

In new enough numpy versions, the creation of a "ragged array" gets this warning, and tells us that we are not creating a simple numeric array.  Instead `M` is an object dtype array, containing a mix of numbers and arrays.

`f_bold` is a list of arrays.  `grad_f` is a (3,3) object dtype array with a mix of floats and arrays.

And in the latest numpy version this kind of error specifies the problem dtype - which as I suspected is 'O', object.

`norm` cannot handle that kind of array.   That's why I asked for the `dtype` of the 2 `norm` arguments.